# Countdown to specific Date and Time in imacros

Tags: macros, imacros

Is it possible to create a countdown to a specific date and time inside imacros? I know that this can be done by scheduling in windows to run the .bat file but this is not helpfull because it first launches firefox and then runs the macro and this can take a few seconds. I want this to be integrated inside the imacro and running all the way until the specific date and time and then continue executing the remaining script. Can anybody write an example script to use it in imacros?

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example, you can try something like this code:

```
' ... '
SET specificTime "2018-02-14T12:00:00"
SET countdownTime EVAL("var ct = parseInt((new Date('{{specificTime}}') - new Date()) / 1000); Math.max(0, ct);")
WAIT SECONDS={{countdownTime}}
' Happy Valentine’s Day! '
```